# How is "p implies q" same as "q unless not p"?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to know how is "p implies q" same as "q unless not p"?
ie how is "$p\Rightarrow q$" same as "$q$ unless $\neg p$" ?

Comment: q unless not p essentially means q if p

Comment: @bnosnehpets we just memorize it?

Comment: @user140087 You just need to get your head around the logic; no need to memorise if you understand.

Comment: @Rammus We should try and understand it as an English sentence?

Comment: No you don't have to. Think about it like this. q is true unless p is not true. Therefore if p is true q is true (because p is not not true).

Comment: @bnosnehpets Thanks Understood!

Comment: @Rammus sorry my comment was in reply to the OP's first comment, not yours

Comment: Isn't `x unless y` same as `x or y`??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, "unless" is not formal mathematical language. It is loose terminology.

Read it longer as "$q$ is true unless $p$ is false." This is read as "either $q$ is true or $p$ is not true."

If this is true, and $p$ is true, it in necessarily the case that $q$ is true.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't!

"p implies q", $p\to q$ is equivalent to "q or not p", $q\vee \neg p$.   This is an inclusive or; it does not exclude the possibility that $q$ and $\neg p$ *may be* both true.

That is not the same thing as "q *unless* not p", which would be an exclusive or.

Comment: I read it in Kenneth Rosen's book on discrete mathematics and I don't think it would be wrong. Moreover the comments and answers of other people are making sense .

Comment: Why do you read "unless" as exclusive? I think that is a perplexing reading.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I agree. The way I read it: "$q$ unless not $p$" means "$q$ is true unless $p$ is false, in which case, we don't know the truthvalue of $q$." Although, arguably, in natural language conversation, the exclusive convention would be expected/interpreted.

Comment: If I say, "I know A is true unless I know p is not true," that doesn't say anything about what I know about A if B is true

Comment: "I'm going for a walk, *unless* it is raining."  @ThomasAndrews.  It is raining.  Am I going for a walk?

Comment: that doesn't tell me you aren't walking tomorrow if it is raining. Only that you might reconsider if it is raining. But that is a programmatic "unless," not a logical "unless." Try it with past tense - all statements are either true or false in predicate logic, not "yet to be determined."

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but I disagree with the last example (given by Aditya Raj).  I would interpret "She finds a good job unless she does not study math" as saying that the only circumstance that would cause her not to find a good job is failing to study math.  But this is not at all implied by the original conditional statement which does guarantee that studying math will lead to a good job, but allows for other possibilities (does not make it a requirement).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose: "If $p$, then $q$."

There are two cases: $p$ can be true, or it can be false. If $p$ is true, then so is $q$. So it follows that $q$ holds unless $p$ is false. Ergo, $q$ unless not $p$.

Now suppose: "$q$ unless $\neg p$."

We're trying to prove "If $p$, then $q$." So assume $p$. Since its not the case that $\neg p$ holds, hence from "$q$ unless $\neg p$" we deduce that $q$ holds. Ergo, if $p$, then $q$.

Answer (score 2):

I teach this class out of Rosen and disagree with this statement as well.  I believe it should be not p unless q.  If you want further evidence, take a look at the very first problem in the following section of 1.2 in which Rosen suddenly conforms to this himself. In this problem, e: "You can edit a protected wikipedia entry" and a: "You are an administrator."  The provided answer to the translation of "You cannot edit a protected wikipedia entry unless you are an administrator" is e implies a.

For another example not from the book, let p: "It rains" and q: "It is wet."  Let us assume p implies q is a truthful conditional statement.  It would make sense to say "It did not rain unless it is wet" (not p unless q).  However, it would NOT make sense to say "It is wet unless it did not rain" (q unless not p)...that is nonsense as the original conditional statement would allow for other ways for it to be wet!

Maybe some will disagree with this, but it is what I go with.

Comment: +1, I agree with your examples. More generally, I think "unless" has different meanings in English depending on the context.

Comment: Taking a UoL course using Rosen and this nearly did my head in. But - did a truth table and q unless ¬P does get the same results as implication.

> p q ¬p p→q  q unless ¬p
> t t  f    t        t
> f t  t    t        t
> t f  f    f        f
> f f  t    t        t

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example. You can find the same in Rosen's book

Conditional statement: if she studies math (p), then she will find a good job (q)

This is of the type: If p, then q.

q unless p:
She finds a good job unless she does not study math.

Here q is true only is ~p (not p) is false. If ~p is true then q will become false.

Hope this helped!