# $(r \wedge \neg s) \rightarrow \neg q$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Answers provided at this link do not satify my question.

[How can this English sentence be translated into a logical expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003705/how-can-this-english-sentence-be-translated-into-a-logical-expression)

In Kenneth Rosan, the answer to this following sentence

> “You cannot ride the roller coaster if you are under 4 feet tall unless you are older than 16 years old.”

is given as,

> $(r \wedge \neg s) \rightarrow \neg q$

Where,

q: “You can ride the roller coaster.”

r: “You are under 4 feet tall.”

s: “ You are older than 16 years old.”

---

My solution:

So, I broke down this compound sentence as follows:

> “[*You cannot ride the roller coaster*] **if** [*you are under 4 feet tall*] **unless** [*you are older than 16 years old.*]”

Now, substituting variables in given compound sentence.

> ($\neg q$) **if** (r **unless** s).

Applying equivalence formula for Q if P $\Leftrightarrow$ P $\to$ Q

> (r **unless** s) $\to$ ($\neg q$)

Now, solving for **unless**. So, (r **unless** s) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($\neg s \to r$) [<sub>ref.</sub>](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~morourke/202-phil/11-Fall/Handouts/Philosophical/Unless.htm)

> ($\neg s \to r$) $\to$ ($\neg q$)

Again solving for $\to$ (implication), we get:

> (s $\lor$ r) $\to$ ($\neg q$)

So, my derivation is obviously wrong and does not match with Kennet Rosen.

> > My Question: What mistake I did? and How to derive the given answer systematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Jay, Kenneth Rosen interprets (r unless s) according to:

$$
\begin{array}{cc|c}
r & s & (r \text{ unless } s) \Leftrightarrow (\neg s \to r) \\\hline
0 & 0 &  0 \\
0 & 1 &  1 \\
1 & 0 &  1 \\
1 & 1 &  1 \\
\end{array}
$$

The issue turns out to be the order of operations for "unless".

You started by breaking it up like this

> “[*You cannot ride the roller coaster*] **if** [*you are under 4 feet tall*] **unless** [*you are older than 16 years old.*]”

And substituted variables to get:

> ($\neg q$) **if** ($r$ **unless** $s$).

If instead we use a different order of operations to group these, it works out with your definition of unless.  That is, we have:

> $((\neg q) \mathbf{\text{ if }} r) \mathbf{\text{ unless }} s$

Now using $(P \mathbf{\text{ if }} Q) \Leftrightarrow (Q \to P)$

> $(r \to \neg q) \mathbf{\text{ unless }} s$

Now using your $(P \mathbf{\text{ unless }} Q) \Leftrightarrow (\neg P \to Q)$

> $\neg s \to (r \to \neg q)$

expanding

> $\neg s \to (\neg r \lor \neg q)$

expanding

> $s \lor (\neg r \lor \neg q)$

This is the same as the other result.
To see this, use associativity of logical or

> $(s \lor \neg r) \lor \neg q$

Then turn it into an implication

> $\neg(s \lor \neg r) \to \neg q$

Use demorgan's law

> $(\neg s \land r) \to \neg q$

(EDIT: Previously I arrived at the answer with the same order of operations, but a different interpretation of unless: $(r \text{ unless } s) = (r \text{ and } \neg s)$. Because "(anything) unless True = True" seriously sounds wrong to me. My interpretation of unless worked in this case, but apparently is not the correct english interpretation. Apologies.)

Comment: For this reason, we are going to translate ‘P unless Q’ with just ¬Q → P unless stated
otherwise from [rpi.edu](http://www.cogsci.rpi.edu/~heuveb/teaching/Logic/CompLogic/Web/Presentations/PropLogicReview.pdf)

Comment: Also, what formula you assumed for "r unless s"?

Comment: @Ubihatt I used no formula. I filled it out how I interpret the phrase in english. So it appears this may just be a natural language ambiguity if you interpret it otherwise.

Comment: Kenneth Rosen also has formula for **unless** which exactly matches with formula embedded in my previous comment.  Please check. **Unless** is a keyword.

Comment: Interpreting "P unless Q" = "¬Q → P", would mean "You cannot ride the roller coaster if you are under 4 feet tall unless you are older than 16 years old." says you cannot ride the roller coaster if you are older than 16 years old, no matter what your height is. Is that really how you interpret that phrase?

Comment: Please refer this [uidaho.edu](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~morourke/202-phil/11-Fall/Handouts/Philosophical/Unless.htm) It conveys my thought.

Comment: @Ubihatt I figured out how to get it to work with that interpretation of unless. It is an order of operations issue.

Comment: Little thing that irks me is how to decide between (($\neg q$ **if** $r$) **unless** $s$) and ($\neg q$) **if** (r **unless** s). How the order to precedence works?!?

Comment: @Ubihatt I think that is a good question, but since I initially interpreted the sentence incorrectly myself (but just happened to get the same final answer), I'm not sure. I guess I need to read some logic books myself.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is to interpret the sentence as $$(\neg q)\ \textbf{if}\ (r\ \textbf{unless}\ s)$$
The correct interpretation is $$  (\neg q\ \textbf{if}\ r)\ \textbf{unless}\ s$$

Comment: You beat me to the punch =) Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

I have a discrete math book by Kenneth Rosen, and here is an excerpt from the book listing the equivalent ways to express $p \implies q$ in English. The one you mentioned is boxed in blue.

[image]

But where did you go wrong? I believe it was at this step

> Now, substituting variables in given compound sentence. 
>   ($\neg q$) **if** (r **unless** s).

The word **unless** does not attach $s$ to $r$; it attaches $s$ with the proposition $\neg q$ **if** $r$. The reason for this is that there was a proposition established prior to **unless**, which was the statement, "You cannot ride the roller coaster if you are under 4 feet tall." That sentence is established as a proposition; it is the $q$ in the table I provided.

So the correct statement using your scheme is

$$\big( \, \neg q \, \textbf{ if }  \, r \, \big) \, \textbf{ unless } \, s,$$
which is equivalent to 
$$\neg s \implies (r \implies \neg q).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: As you saw, I initially interpreted unless differently, and just happened to get the right answer erroneously. So I learned something here too. But I'm struggling how "True unless True" evaluates to True.  "The dog is angry unless the dog is fed".  If the dog is angry and the dog is fed, I would interpret that as false.  Is my english screwed up, or what am I missing?

Comment: Maybe what you're missing is that $F \implies T$ is true (similarly, $F \implies F$ is true). "The dog is angry unless the dog is fed," which is the same as "If the dog is not fed, then the dog is angry." If the dog is indeed fed, then the statement "the dog is not fed" is false, of course. But then the statement "If the dog is not fed, then the dog is angry" is actually a true statement (a false hypothesis can be used to derive any conclusion). The only way the statement could be false is when the dog is not fed, but the dog is not angry. Does that help?

Comment: To add to what I said, "True unless True" is equivalent to "False implies True," which is a  true statement, per the definition of "implies" that we have agreed to adopt. We have agreed that $p \implies q$ is false if and only if $p$ is true and $q$ is false, and $p \implies q$ is true otherwise.

Comment: @HBrown Here is a link that could elucidate this topic, if indeed my interpretation was your correct intention: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583209/false-implies-true-is-a-true-statement/1583244

Comment: I understand how implications work. I can see that "If the dog is not fed, then the dog is angry" does not give us any information if the dog _is_ fed, and so the dog could be angry or not in that case and the statement is holds true. But to me (again, maybe my english is screwed up), "The dog is angry unless the dog is fed" says more. To me I would interpret that statement as "false" if "the dog is fed" and "the dog is angry".

Comment: I've come up with other examples with "unless", and I interpret them slightly different based on context, so I guess my english is just sloppy. Wow. This is crazy I've never noticed this til today. Now I'm curious to ask a bunch of engineering friends versus math friends and see how they interpret the english phrases.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. I don't think it's your English. I was looking at other sites and papers, and there isn't a consensus as to what "unless" means in general, for it can be construed in different ways in different contexts. This link is particularly helpful as to why in logic this particular convention was adopted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295106/how-is-p-implies-q-same-as-q-unless-not-p

Comment: You might also be interested in these other links regarding the ambiguity of "unless" outside of mathematics: Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/52585m/interpreting_the_word_unless_in_symbolic_logic/ 

and a linguistic paper: http://web.stanford.edu/~danlass/Nadathur-Lassiter-unless-SuB.pdf

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks for all the follow up links.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck.